# Is there a way to convert a CICS bms file to EPIScreenRecord JAVA class?

Tags: cics

Is there a way to convert a CICS bms file to EPIScreenRecord JAVA class similar to how BMSMapConvert converts a bms file to xxxMap and xxxScreenHandler JAVA classes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no utility to convert BMS maps to records for use with the EPI JCA resource adapter as BMSMapConvert only works with the EPI support classes.